# How to restore the application state when using Dagger2 + MVP

Tags: android, mvp, dagger-2, android-mvp

**EDITED 2**

I have an Activity with multiple fragments. The Activity manages a form with several steps, each step being a Fragment.
My implementation follows the MVP design pattern and I'm using Dagger2 to inject the components (Presenters, Models, ...)

The data collected at each step of the form are stored in an unique object shared between Fragment. This object is retains as long as the Activity is alive (using `@ActivityScope` and is injected so the Activity is not directly linked to it.

Each Fragment access this object through their Model. So neither the Fragment, its Presenter nor the Activity's Presenter have directly access to it.

When the application is destroyed the Dagger Component (retaining the Object's instance) is destroyed. When the user returns to the app, the system tries to restore the app in its previous state. But as the Object is recreated from scratch, all the data previously entered by the user are lost.

As mentioned in the comments below, I should use the `onSaveInstanceState` method to save the data in the bundle and restore them in the `onCreate`.
But as the Activity and the Object can't directly communicate, how I'm supposed to achieve that?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

> In all tutorials I have seen (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2)), Dagger2's component
>   is stored in the Application class as you generally need some objects
>   to remains during the all life time of the app.
>
> At the moment I have an Activity with multiple fragments. The Activity
>   manages a form with several steps, each step being a Fragment.
>
> My implementation follows the MVP design pattern.  The data collected
>   at each step of the form are stored in a unique object shared between
>   Fragment's presenters. To manage it more easily and not have to pass
>   the object to the next step manually, this object is directly injected
>   to the Fragment presenter. This object has an `@ActivityScope` and is
>   retains as long as the Activity remains.
>
> As I'm using `@Singletons` (e.g. to keep Retrofit clients), the
>   Activity component is a `@Subcomponent` of the global one, managed by
>   the Application as described in the example.
>
> **EDITED**
>
> The problem I have, is when the app is stopped and the Application and
>   Activity destroyed, when the app is restored, the Activity and
>   Fragment I were on are restored too but I've lost all the data entered
>   (as the Dagger component has been destroyed).
>
> So I was wondering how I'm supposed to managed that?

Comment: This sounds a bit odd "the Application is destroyed but not the Activity". Activities live within an Application, they can't exist by themselves.

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Yeah, I'm wrong, the Activity seems to be destroyed too. But what happen is the app is restored to the Activity and Fragment I was on when I left the app. So I'm on the middle a the form but I've lost all the data entered

Comment: Your problem is not related to Dagger. What you want to achieve is to persist some data. Search for these keywords and you'll find lots of information.

Comment: Dagger does not store data for you. You still need to use `onSaveInstanceState` for configuration changes, or write your data to disk (e.g. SharedPreferences) if you want to prevent losing it.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that, but how do you manage that? In my case the data are in an object injected in the Model. The `onSaveInstanceState` is in the View which doesn't know anything about the Model. (I follow the MVP design pattern)

Comment: If you are not handling state persistence properly then either the design pattern or your implementation of it is incorrect. Activity is not a View, it's the process entry point. You are disobeying the Activity contract (which is to show ui **and persist/restore state**)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes something is obviously wrong in my implementation. How am I supposed to manage onSaveInstanceState in an MVP + injection structure without turning my code into an un-maintainable nightmare?

Comment: I can recommend [this library I wrote specifically for this purpose! :D](https://github.com/Zhuinden/state-bundle) this lets you save state into a Parcelable so even the state persistence logic is testable. This is a Presenter responsibility, after all. Restore state of presenter before attaching the view to it (if such state exists).

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It's an interesting approach but it doesn't really solve my problem, even if it helps a bit. As described, I have an Object storing the data entered by the user. This object is common for all the fragments of the from process (means it's the same shared instance). This object remains as long as the Activity is alive. It's managed by Dagger2, means it's neither hold by the Activity nor its Presenter. It's stored in the Activity Component by Dagger...

Comment: ...All the Fragments access this object via their Model, which is linked to their Presenter and not the Fragment directly. The state of this object should not be managed by the Fragments. I think it should be saved when the `onSaveInstanceState` of the Activity is called, and restore in the `onCreate`. The problem is: I don't know how to notify this object that it needs to save the data in the activity bundle (as the Activity is not linked to it), and how to restore them.

Comment: Delegate `onSaveInstanceState()` call through the system. You have an `attach/detach`, no? Have a `save/restore` as well.

Comment: Yes, on the Activity Presenter. But the object I want to save is neither in the Activity nor in it's Presenter, despite being hold by the Activity's Dagger Component  (I've updated the question)

Comment: Obtain it and restore its state from Bundle if applicable..

Comment: As a side note: don’t keep Retrofit as a Singleton - use Reusable scope